# Emphasis tag breaks view on mobile

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm looking for help/feedback from the Google team on the `<emphasis>` tag. I tried to use it to emphasize choices a user can make.

`"<speak> Would you like to listen to <emphasis level="moderate"> this </emphasis> or <emphasis level="moderate"> that? </emphasis></speak>"`

This broke the speech output, as a quick fix for speech, I wrapped the whole string in a emphasis tag with a low level.

For reference: `"<speak> <emphasis level="low"> Would you like to listen to <emphasis level="moderate"> this </emphasis> or <emphasis level="moderate"> that? </emphasis></emphasis></speak>"`

On a mobile phone, though, the `<emphasis>` tag adds a new line before and after any string that is emphasized. There probably is a workaround for this on my side, but I also wanted to report this as a bug.

The output that I get on a mobile phone looks like this:

`"Would you like to listen to 
this
or 
that?"`

Comment: Can you also include exactly how you're sending it back? (what API, what fields int he API, etc) Seeing the code and/or JSON will help.

Comment: @Prisoner This bug easy to reproduce in TTS simulator of Actions console. Try this one:
 <speak>
   <p>
    Do you like <emphasis level="strong">red</emphasis> car?
   </p>
   <p>
    Do you like red car?
   </p>
 </speak>

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets - But that doesn't seem to be the issue Julia has since it doesn't have <p> tags. (My answer contains content that I cut and pasted directly from the TTS simulator after testing it.) (Yours also played fine when I tried it in the TTS simulator.)

Comment: @Prisoner I have added <p> just to have a nice separation of 2 sentences. but sure we could skip them and still have the problem of <emphasis> which breaks the tone of question sentence. Btw you can more easily check the problem in something like that (in 1st sentence you would hear word "comma" which should alter pronunciation instead):

<speak>
  <p>
   Do you like <emphasis level="strong">red</emphasis>, <emphasis level="strong">blue</emphasis> or <emphasis level="strong">green</emphasis> car?
  </p>
  <p>
   Do you like red, blue or green car?
  </p>
</speak>

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets - so you're saying the problem is with the pacing of the SSML rendering? That didn't sound like what the OP was saying the problem was, unless I'm misunderstanding what "broke the speech output" meant.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're sending this back either as text or as text-to-speech. If you send it back using SSML with the appropriate `<speak>` tag surrounding it, it should work. So it might look something like

```
<speak>
Would you like to listen to <emphasis level="strong"> this </emphasis> or <emphasis level="strong"> that? </emphasis>
</speak>
```

You should also make sure that you're sending it back using the `ssml` field and not the `textToSpeech` field or anything similar.

Comment: I forgot to write that I wrapped it in `<speak>` tag as well. I'll edit the question. Thank you though!